# LEDs for model ship

Tags: led, remote-control, model

My dad built a model ship and wants some lights - kind of like the attached photo.

His request:  Small, the LED must fit in a 1/2 inch space. The LED must be dim and amber in color,, flicker if possible and be powered by a nine volt battery. I would like eight of these set ups but not wired in series, also I would like them to turn off and on remotely. Finally the wires must be long, two feet and very thin but flexible.

I'm still a newbie.  If you wouldn't mind just giving me some ideas on where to begin.  I was thinking of using a Nano.  Plus I used 9V batteries on Arduino projects before and they really don't work very well.  Unless I'm doing something wrong.

What are your thoughts?

[image: Ship]

Comment: I found remote controlled battery powered fairy lights on Amazon for $12.  The string is about 20 feet long.  It looks, from the pictures online, to be wired in parallel.  Could I modify somehting like this?  Cut the length down?  If so, would I need dropping resistors?  If so, how do I calc?  Sorry for all the questions.  Just trying to think of solutions.

Comment: *This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.*

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01M19H8K2/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&th=1

Comment: The “fairy lights” are wired in parallel, so you can cut the string, just take care not to let the exposed ends short together. This would be much easier and efficient than introducing a microprocessor, developing a remote, etc,

Comment: _turn off and on remotely_ - by switch? Or something else?

Comment: It's always worth noting that 9V batteries are terrible, so whenever possible you should use another form factor like AA, AAA or 18650.  That said you don't need a lot of power here so you could run on a 9v for an hour or more.

Answer (score 1):

Consider modifying some [flickering LED tea lights](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=led+flickering+tea+lights). These have (pseudo-)random flickering patterns that are more likely to be useful than the regular patterns on fairy light strings. The flickering tea lights I have already have dim amber LEDs.

To fit the LEDs in small lanterns you may need to unsolder the LED from its control board and hide the board inside the hull. You can buy thin wire separately and cut to length as required to connect the LED back to the board. Remember that LEDs are polarity sensitive so will need to be connected back in the original orientation. There are plenty of guides to recognising LED polarity on the Web; you may see a flat spot on the package, look at the shape of the metal supports within the package or check with the diode test feature on a DMM. Use one tea light per lantern, all the lanterns will flicker independently improving the effect.

My tea lights run from a 3 V coin cell rather than a 9 V battery and I expect that's typical.  If you get a battery holder that takes a [pair of AA cells](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=3v+aa+battery+holder&ref=nb_sb_noss_1) you can wire all the control boards in parallel (observing polarity again) and power them from a single point. Add one switch and you can control all the lanterns from one place. You can even get a battery holder with [a built-in switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076C7S2VN).